# I failed with functions. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function

I had to write a C# console application that takes two Double precision numbers. The program will then call functions to the computer with the following values sum, difference, average, dividend, and modulus.

I did the above but failed to use **FUNCTIONS**. Can someone explain how to use functions in the code I wrote below?

Thanks in advance for anyone who reads and helps.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Hello! This application takes two provided double percision numbers 
and will show you the Sum, Difference, Average, Product, Divided, and modulus of those two numbers.
The two numbers we will be working with are 10.4200 and 6.8640.
After, you'll be able to try it for yourself!
Press ENTER to display results");

            Console.ReadLine();

            double value1 = 10.4200;
            double value2 = 6.8640;

            double sum = value1 + value2;
            double difference = value1 - value2;
            double average = (value1 + value2) / 2;
            double product = value1 * value2;
            double divided = value1 / value2;
            double modulus = value1 % value2;

            Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum);
            Console.WriteLine("Difference = " + difference);
            Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average);
            Console.WriteLine("Product = " + product);
            Console.WriteLine("Divided = " + divided);
            Console.WriteLine("modulus = " + modulus);

            Console.WriteLine("Now try it for yourself!");

            Console.WriteLine("Go ahead and enter your first number");
            double value3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Now, enter your second number");
            double value4 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double sum2 = value3 + value4;
            double difference2 = value3 - value4;
            double average2 = (value3 + value4) / 2;
            double product2 = value3 * value4;
            double divided2 = value3 / value4;
            double modulus2 = value3 % value4;

            Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum2);
            Console.WriteLine("Difference = " + difference2);
            Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average2);
            Console.WriteLine("Product = " + product2);
            Console.WriteLine("Divided = " + divided2);
            Console.WriteLine("modulus = " + modulus2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, @bmatthew, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To clarify, are you saying you want to refactor your code to use functions? What's driving that requirements? E.g., is the goal to parameterize repetitive logic? Centralize the code so it can be called from other contexts, and not just when you first run the application? Understanding your objectives would be useful here.

Comment: In C# a function is also known as a method. It can be a static (class level) or instance (/object) level member of a class. It can take zero or more parameters and return a value (or `void`, which indicates that it returns no value). What you want to do is create a function, say `Sum` that takes two double values, calculates the sum of the two values and returns it as a double. Then create a function for each of your calculations. Finally, instead of directly calculating things in your `Main` code you call the function. We generally don't do homework, but I'm ok with explaining it

Comment: One other comment is that when you accepting user input in a specific format, you have to assume that your users will mess up and type something incorrectly. The `double.Parse` function will *throw* an `Exception` when given an incorrectly formatted string. Consider using `double.TryParse`, it returns a boolean (a true/false value) indicating whether the string was parsable, and returns the value in an output parameter. That way, if the user messes up, you can loop around and say "Try again"

Answer (score 2):

Rough Example:

```
private static double Add(double d1, double d2)
{
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

Then in you main function:

```
 double sum2 = value3 + value4;
// Change this to
 double sum2 = Add(value3, value4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write the following method

```
private void Compute(double value1, double value2)
{
    double sum = value1 + value2;
    double difference = value1 - value2;
    double average = (value1 + value2) / 2;
    double product = value1 * value2;
    double divided = value1 / value2;
    double modulus = value1 % value2;

    Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum);
    Console.WriteLine("Difference = " + difference);
    Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average);
    Console.WriteLine("Product = " + product);
    Console.WriteLine("Divided = " + divided);
    Console.WriteLine("modulus = " + modulus);
}
```

Then your code becomes

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Hello! This application takes two provided double 
percision numbers 
and will show you the Sum, Difference, Average, Product, Divided, and modulus of those 
two numbers.
The two numbers we will be working with are 10.4200 and 6.8640.
After, you'll be able to try it for yourself!
Press ENTER to display results");

    Console.ReadLine();

    double value1 = 10.4200;
    double value2 = 6.8640;
    Compute(value1, value2);

    Console.WriteLine("Now try it for yourself!");

    Console.WriteLine("Go ahead and enter your first number");
    double value3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Now, enter your second number");
    double value4 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Compute(value3, value4);
}
```

Comment: The `Compute` method is a subroutine and not a function. I'm not sure if that answers the question.